# Tool to create UI for Linux (Gnome) shell scripts

Tags: linux, user-interface, bash, shell, gnome

I'm writing a bunch of Linux shell scripts with complex selections. For now I use zenity for prompts. I'd rather use something where I can show more than one UI element at a time and query it in a script (e.g. a list and some checkboxed and a file picker and an entry field.
What are my options?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe [GTKDialog](http://linux.pte.hu/~pipas/gtkdialog/) comes with extended gtk-ified versions of the popular [curses based dialog utility](http://linux.die.net/man/1/dialog) for shell scripts.

I'm not sure if it will serve the complexity of your needs, however. In any event, its a place to start.

Answer (score 2):

You're going to have to move up to something more capable. PyGTK with Glade is fairly powerful, and Python is easy enough to pick up.

Answer (score 1):

[autoglade](http://autoglade.sourceforge.net/) could also be of help to give your scripts of commands a graphical user interface, in many cases with no additional programming.

Some docs and tutorials can be found [here](http://codtech.com/wiki/index.php/Autoglade).

Answer (score 1):

zenity 3 now has a option to create a form with multiple elements. See the following bug report

https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=412493

Answer (score 1):

[Yad](http://code.google.com/p/yad/) is a fork of Zenity that adds almost as much functionality as Gtkdialog. Mostly backward compatible too.